# How does LuaJIT wrap C data types with the FFI?

Tags: c, lua, ffi, luajit, cross-language

Let's say that I have the following LuaJIT code:

```
local ffi = require "ffi"

ffi.cdef[[
    typedef struct { int num; } container;
]]

local a = ffi.new("container")
a.num = 10

library.doSomethingTo(a)
```

and let's say that `library.doSomethingTo` is defined by the following C code:

```
int doSomethingDo(lua_State *L) {
    //code here
}
```

what code would need to go at `//code here` in order to make `library.doSomethingTo(a)` print 10?

Comment: So, to recap: you want to take an object created through FFI and talk to it through the Lua API.

Comment: @NicolBolas I guess? I am not knowledgeable enough to confirm that that is an accurate summary of my question.

Comment: You can use C exported functions with `ffi.cdef` as well, but if you want to use standard Lua C functions then you need to parse parameters into LuaVM somehow